# Return false and e.preventDefault() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am reading article about Javascript.

I have created a small example:

html:

```
<a id="href1" href="https://www.google.ru/">1</a>
<a id="href2" href="https://www.google.ru/">2</a>
```

js:

```
 href1.onClick = function () {
    alert("href1");
    return false;
}
href2.addEventListener = ("click", function (e) {
    alert("href2");
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

I expected that I will see alert and redirect will not be executed. At my local PC I don't see alert but redirect happens.
**What did I do wrong?**

https://jsfiddle.net/hr1cbu2j/

Comment: @Downvoter, clarify why?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: @Jonathan Wheeler At first I need learn true javascript

Comment: @JonathanWheeler why should the OP use jQuery?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Using jQuery doesn't change the language you're writing your code in. Just the API you're working with (jQuery's instead of the DOM's). I'm not saying use it, I'm just saying, using jQuery isn't in any way not using "true JavaScript."

Comment: @MelanciaUK At first I thought it was a problem of not properly finding href2. (I'm more familiar with DOM editing with jQuery than with pure JS).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Jquery only wrapper over pure js. I want to know pure js at once

Comment: `onClick !== onclick` Case matters. And nowhere in the [addEventListener documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) shows that syntax. And you really should declare varaibles and not reference elements by ids directly.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Re-read my comment above. *"Jquery only wrapper over pure js"* is a false statement and more importantly, a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder jquery uses pure javascripte inside ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: You're missing the fundamental point: JavaScript is a *programming language*, not an API. JS doesn't have `addEventListener` (for instance). That's part of **something else**, called the DOM. It's a collection of objects and methods (an API) provided by the browser that lets you manipulate the doc. You can use that API in JS code. jQuery also provides an API to let you manipulate the doc, which you also use in JS code. (And yes, jQuery uses the DOM internally.) It's important to understand what you're learning in order to learn it.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: So you're probably right now trying to learn *two* things: JavaScript (the language), and the DOM (the API in the browser letting you manipulate the page). Alternately, if you liked, you could learn JavaScript and jQuery's API (I'm not suggesting it, I'm just trying to separate the concepts for you). Or you might learn JavaScript and Vue.js. Or JavaScript and Angular. The DOM, jQuery, Vue.js, and Angular are all ways of manipulating and using the document. You use them with a programming language (JavaScript, or CoffeeScript, or TypeScript, ...).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks a lot for your clarification

Answer (score 2):

Your first example uses `onClick`, but should use `onclick`. JavaScript and the DOM are case-sensitive. But I wouldn't use `onclick`.

Your second example should be:

```
href2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("href2");
}, false);
```

1. The syntax was just way off and should have been giving you an error in the web console.
2. Paranoia tells me to prevent the default before showing the `alert`, because `alert` is a very weird thing and has odd behaviors on some browsers (like Firefox).

---

Side note: I'd strongly advise against relying on the automatic globals created by giving elements `id`s. *Yes*, it is (now) specified behavior, but the global namespace is just way too crowded and conflicts are easy to have and hard to diagnose. Use `document.getElementById` instead:

```
document.getElementById("href2").addEventListener(...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener` like this:

```
var href2 = document.getElementById('href2');

href2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("href2");
});
```

Comment: please explain difference with my example

Comment: Explaination: The answer here uses the correct syntax unlike the original code.

Comment: lol, thanx for explaination. `addEventListener = ("click"` <- no need `=` here